# Avoiding multiple if statements in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, textbox

I have a field EmpID (textbox) where user manually enters a 6 digit code. If he enters less than 6 digit then we need to add "0" as prefix to make it a 6 digit code. Example if enters 123, we must make it 000123. If he enters 1234, we must make it 001234.

I want an efficient way for handling this situation. I want to avoid writing multiple if statements. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: I recommend using [String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @adv12 that could be an answer

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency. An extra `if` isn't going to bring your machine to its knees. I'd just worry about messy code.

Comment: Tried this link? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, make sure wherever you are storing the value it is stored as a string, if you try to store it as a number type you'll lose your padded 0s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
tbValue = tbValue.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `PadLeft` function as below

```
myString = myString.PadLeft(6, '0');
```